# Not able to run SQL queries in AS400, run into Invalid Token errors

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

In AS400, how can i perform arithmetic operations (like +, -) on fields.

- For the query `Select id, sum(field1+field2) as Total from table
  group by id`, getting the following error msg in German "[IBM][System
  i Access ODBC-Treiber][DB2 für i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token & ungültig.
  Gültige Token: + - AS `<IDENTIFIER>`." English Translation is something
  like "[IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5/OS] SQL0104 -
  Token `<END Instruction>` invalid. Valid tokens: CL AS IN LOG OUT DATA
  `<identifier>`."
- For the query `Select count(*) from (select distinct field1 from table where field2="abc"`, getting the following error msg "[IBM][System i Access ODBC-Treiber][DB2 für i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token `<ENDE DER ANWEISUNG>` ungültig. Gültige Token: AS CL IN LOG OUT DATA `<IDENTIFIER>`."
- For a query with sub-query got the following error msg
  "[IBM][System i Access ODBC-Treiber][DB2 für i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token & ungültig. Gültige Token: `<` `>` = `<>` `<=` `!<` `!>` `!=` `>=` `¬<` `¬>` `¬=` IN NOT."

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my sql queries.

Comment: It looks like you are showing us pseudocode, when query probably had other column names and table names. By creating psuedocode, it looks like you have introduced new syntax errors. Please show us your **actual code**, so we can accurately diagnose your **actual problem**.

Comment: I am really sorry for that pseudo code. This client database has little sensitive data. My query(with dummy names) goes like this "select EDS,  sum(val(SDS)) as totalh  from tbl1 where EDS & '' like  '201305[0-9][0-9]'  and siteds in(select distinct SITE from tbl2 where H_04 in ('1234') and PERIOD =201305) group by EDS order by EDS". Issue is NOT with the reserved keyword Table. Had to use & and two single quotes ('') because the field EDS is of type Numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TABLE` is a reserved word.  [SQL Reference: Reserved schema names and reserved words](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzresword.htm).

- Single quotes escape a string literal
- Double quotes escape a reserved word (similar to brackets in TSQL)

[SQL Reference: Identifiers](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzch2iden.htm)

The queries could be re-written as:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(FIELD1 + FIELD2) AS TOTAL FROM "TABLE" GROUP BY ID
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1 FROM "TABLE" WHERE FIELD2 = 'ABC')
```

---

**UPDATE**

DB/2 for i does not support your method of numeric to character conversion or the type of character comparison used in your LIKE query.

The query can be re-written as:

```
SELECT eds, SUM(INT(sds)) AS totalh 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE eds BETWEEN 20130500 AND 20130599 
AND siteds IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT site 
    FROM tbl2 
    WHERE H_04 IN ('1234') AND PERIOD = 201305
) 
GROUP BY eds
ORDER BY eds
```

You may need to use `DEC` instead of `INT` depending upon the definition of field `sds`.

SQL Reference:
- [`INT`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscaintfunc.htm)
- [`DEC`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscadec.htm)
- [`BETWEEN`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzbetween.htm)

Comment: This is a good answer for what was posted.  But based on the generic names given and issues with the errors he shows, it looks to me like the SQL code was turned into pseudocode after copying the errors.  So we may have been following a red herring.

Comment: @James, Thanks sooooo much for the answer. I'll make the modification and have the client tested this. I'll give you an update ASAP.

Comment: @James, Thanks a ton for the answer. You are an absolute genius. It works well. Thank you-Sri.

Answer (score 1):

Is the table's name really 'table'?

Odd as it seems, if I use the SQL statement you indicated as is, I get the same error... but if I change 'table' to 'table1', it just complains that it can't find 'table1'.

Comment: I'd say you're on the right trail.  It appears he changed the table name before posting.  In the second query it looks like he originally had something like `sum(field1 & field2)` but when he retyped it, the `&` became a `+`.